# Vue.js filtering on array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, filtering

I am trying to filter an array using a computed property in vue.js.  I would like to search on on multiple fields, name, state, tags etc.

My data:

```
events: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name of event',
    url: '#',
    datetime: '2017-05-10T00:00:00Z',
    description: 'The full text of the event',
    state: 'VIC',
    tags: [
      'ordinary',
      'advanced'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Another event',
    url: '#',
    datetime: '2017-05-12T00:00:00Z',
    description: 'The full text of the event',
    state: 'VIC',
    tags: [
      'beginner'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Great event',
    url: '#',
    datetime: '2017-05-18T00:00:00Z',
    description: 'The full text of the event',
    state: 'NSW',
    tags: [
      'beginner'
    ]
  }
]
```

},

The following function works as expected, however I cant work out how to have it search the items in 'tags' (commented out).

```
searchevents: function(){
  let result = this.events
  if (this.filterValue){
    result = result.filter(event =>
      event.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterValue.toLowerCase()) ||
      event.state.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterValue.toLowerCase())
      // event.tags.toLowerCase().values().includes(this.filterValue.toLowerCase())
    )
  }
  return result
}
```

The following returns a blank array, this method works ok when i have done it in angular but not in vue.

```
searchevents2: function(){
  var searchRegex = new RegExp(this.filterValue,'i')
  this.events.filter(function(event){
    return !self.filterValue || searchRegex.test(event.name) || searchRegex.test(event.state)
  })
}
```

Ideally I would either like to be able to list array items to filter by or just filter by the entire array.

Appreciate any help, first post here so be gentle.  I have a lot more experience with Python than Javascript so i may also use incorrect terminology at times.

Comment: I recommend you to shorten your question and code.

Comment: I think your question is fine. The only thing I would add that really helps is a working example that can be modified to fix your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You weren't too far off.

For your `searchEvents` filter, you just needed to add the tag filter. Here's how you might do that.

```
searchevents: function(){
    let result = this.events
    if (!this.filterValue)
      return result

    const filterValue = this.filterValue.toLowerCase()

    const filter = event => 
        event.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        event.state.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        event.tags.some(tag => tag.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))

    return result.filter(filter)
}
```

[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) is a standard array method that returns true if any element of the array passes your test.

```
searchevents2: function(){
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(this.filterValue,'i')
    return this.events.filter(event => 
      !this.filterValue || searchRegex.test(event.name) || searchRegex.test(event.state))
}
```

With `searchEvents2` you really only left an errant `self` in there. Either you needed to set `self` before you executed the filter, or, as I have done here, turned it into an arrow function.

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yboKQb?editors=1010).

Comment: Thankyou so much.  Perfect explanation and it works great.

I revised the second function and added a test for event.tags and it works great and somewhat neater code I think.

Comment: @KyleHadland Glad to help :)

Answer (score 6):

```js
const app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    search: '',
    userList: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Prem"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Chandu"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Shravya"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredAndSorted(){
     // function to compare names
     function compare(a, b) {
       if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
       if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
       return 0;
     }
      
     return this.userList.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
     }).sort(compare)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
        <label>Search Users:</label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in filteredAndSorted">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```