# vue v-for with filter gives error

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm trying to use a local filter with `v-for` but I'm getting an error

> Property or method "filterByTitle" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Code below

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col pt-5">

      <ul class="blog-list-single" v-for="(post, index) in posts | filterByTitle" :key="index">
        <li class="title">{{ post.title }}</li>
        <li class="author">{{ post.author }}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        posts: [
          { title: 'a', author: 'nd' },
          { title: 'b', author: 'nd' },
          { title: 'c', author: 'nd' },
        ],
        selectedValue: 'a',
      }
    },
    filters: {
      filterByTitle(value) {
        return value.filter(el => el.title == this.selectedValue)
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot use a filter like that in Vue 2. Use a computed property.

Comment: Yep, Vue 2 removed filters. Bert's answer below solves this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are [limited in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) primarily to formatting string interpolations. You can also now use them in v-bind expressions.

In Vue 2, you would filter a list like this using a computed property.

```js
console.clear()
new Vue({
  el: ".row",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [{
          title: 'a',
          author: 'nd'
        },
        {
          title: 'b',
          author: 'nd'
        },
        {
          title: 'c',
          author: 'nd'
        },
      ],
      selectedValue: 'a',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filterByTitle() {
      // return the whole list if there is no filter value
      if (!this.selectedValue) return this.posts
      // otherwise return the list filtered by title
      return this.posts.filter(el => el.title == this.selectedValue)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pt-5">

    <ul class="blog-list-single" v-for="(post, index) in filterByTitle" :key="index">
      <li class="title">{{ post.title }}</li>
      <li class="author">{{ post.author }}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to be able to have multiple filters. For example `filterByTitle` and `filterByAuthor`. Can you do that with computed values?

Comment: @locnguyen Sure. You would build your computed property to take multiple filters into account as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772871/38065